# Static website on Heroku Cedar

Tags: static, heroku, rack, cedar

I tried following the instructions [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-on-heroku) in order to create a static website on Heroku's Cedar stack.

I have put the site up [here](https://github.com/kushpatel72/hgtr).

When I try to push the app (using "git push heroku master"), I get the following error:

```
Kushs-MacBook-Air:hgtr kushpatel$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.29 KiB, done.
Total 7 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:gentle-warrior-1301.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:gentle-warrior-1301.git'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am on the latest ruby/rack/heroku

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The instructions are for Bamboo stack which would have had Rack installed - the Cedar stack is entirely empty so you need to have rack installed.

You need to add a Gemfile with

```
source :rubygems

gem 'rack'
```

`bundle` it and then add the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to git and repush.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are for the Bamboo stack.

The cedar stack needs a [Procfile](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to be able to identify how to run your app.

Something like this in your Procfile should do the trick - assuming you're using thin:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

Comment: Procfiles aren't used to detect the app types - config.ru is sufficient. They will automatically run a web process for you.

Comment: Ah, well said. Completely forgot about that. Tks